# Create professional graphs for reports without underlying data?

Tags: gratis, graphs

When writing descriptions of general trends, orders of magnitude, change over time, etc, it is often useful to include simple trend graphs like this:

[image]

**What tool can I use to create professional looking line graphs without having to provide underlying data?**

I'm envisioning a web-app where I can add axes and data series, and drag the lines to appear how I want them. **I don't want to draw the lines with a mouse** -- they always end up looking choppy. I want something that *looks* like it was produced with a nice smooth data trend.

Requirements:

- Free
- Ideally web-based or platform-independent
- Produce a *.png (preferred) or *.pdf file (or at the very least a table of the resulting data, so I can reproduce the graph in excel)

Comment: In other words, you're looking for an image editor that can draw [Bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), lines, and text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) is:

- free
- cross platform
- excellent
- produces .svg files (best for vectors) but can also produce numerous other formats.

### Use

By using the Line & Curves tool [image: Line & Curve] to place the start, turning and end points then the point edit [image: Point Edit] to select the path and selecting make the selected points into a smooth curve [image: Smooth Curve], *(plus of course setting the colours and adding the text).*

Like many tools Inkscape requires a little practice and familiarity. The results of a couple of minutes:
[image: Cropped Curves]

Of course you have more than a little choice of format:
[image: Save As]

Comment: I've used Inkscape, but would this solution require me to draw lines with a mouse? Or is there something more sophisticated? I removed "freehand" from the title as that's not really what I want. I want something that generates curves.

Comment: Inkscape has Bezier lines. Acceptable for unscientific graphs, and certainly easier to "shape" than if you had to modify fake data in order to generate a nice curve.

Comment: @LShaver: You do not need to draw smooth freehand lines with the mouse - see expanded answer.

Comment: This is minor, but... could you crop that image of the plot?

Comment: @LShaver - Yep done by simply selecting the original contents (Ctrl-A) then Export Selected Area.